# Write and Load widgets remotely from Firestore database to flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app and I want to be able create or edit the appearance of widgets on a particular screen remotely by writing the code into a field on my Firestore database and loading it into the app without  having the user download an update too because these widgets may change a lot, my only idea was to  add the dart code to a field and have flutter load that widget remotely , is this possible, if I saved the dart code as a string, it would import it as a string, how do I remove the quotes? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If It is simply possible than everyone must have to do this implement.
But it is not that simple, currently there is no way to directly convert string into Widget(look and feel),

But if you create `json` file according to look and feel and then apply each widget property according to `json`, that's work pretty good. Try out the
**[Decorator Pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=Decorator%20Pattern&oq=Decorator%20Pattern&aqs=chrome..69i57.326j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** for adding some dynamic property on child widget.